# What is the importance of the souvenir from Lagos, Nigeria?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-origins-wolverine

In *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*, what is the importance of souvenir acquired from Lagos, Nigeria, that William Stryker wants the source of.

Answer (score 7):

### The souvenir is made of Adamantium, which Stryker wants more of for his experiements.

As explained [here](https://xmenmovies.fandom.com/wiki/William_Stryker):

> During one of their missions, while under Stryker's command, Team X is sent to search for and retrieve a mysterious meteorite - later discovered as Adamantium - from a diamond trafficking operation in Lagos, Nigeria. They attack a compound there and after defeating the compound's security forces, they obtain a mysterious rock - later discovered as a meteorite fragment that fell from the sky as a meteor - from the compound's leader and discover that it originates from a remote village.

Comment: The meteor itself can't be adamantium, as adamantium is an alloy. Even Wikia's own links to adamantium claim it was made from elements in the meteorite (this element being vibranium), despite their own page making the claim it's adamantium. However, I believe that this meteorite was made of vibranium, that was made into adamantium (an alloy of steel and vibranium) and forged into the souvenir.